# platformBrowserDynamic Bundle size in angular is huge

Tags: angular, webpack

Hello this is very new territory for me currently using webpack with angular 6 and use webpack for build. I notci my platformBrowserDynamic  is huge when bootstrapping my Appmodule See photo for refrence[image]

As you can see its pretty large anyway to bring this down ? Any way to be more efficient in this regard?

Here is my current build in main.ts

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: It’s your entire app module..

Comment: I'm newer to this area are you saying that is my entire app which explains the size?

Comment: Yes, probably. It also contains app.module. Sp if you like to reduce size, you could consider going for lazy modules to make the initial app load smaller.

Comment: Thank you for this insight I understand now please answer the question so I can mark it as correct for you! Credit where credit  is due!